# Need to optimize a SQL Query

Tags: sql

Here is the `where` clause of the SQL. when I'm removing this part, it's taking 3 mins to execute, with this one it's taking more than 15 mins
there are almost 9000 records in DB

```
WHERE username = 'xyz' AND 
( 
    ( acceptedfordeliverytime BETWEEN '2012-9-1' AND '2013-1-29' ) 
    OR 
    ( 
        YEAR(acceptedfordeliverytime) = YEAR('2013-1-29') 
        AND 
        MONTH(acceptedfordeliverytime) = MONTH('2013-1-29') 
        AND 
        DAY(acceptedfordeliverytime) = DAY('2013-1-29')
    ) 
    OR 
    ( 
        YEAR(acceptedfordeliverytime) = YEAR('2012-9-1') 
        AND 
        MONTH(acceptedfordeliverytime) = MONTH('2012-9-1') 
        AND 
        DAY(acceptedfordeliverytime) = DAY('2012-9-1') 
    )
)
```

Comment: For starters instead of using YEAR('2012-9-1') couldn't you simply put in the value of year

Comment: Also consider making a proper indexes.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use:

```
WHERE username = 'xyz' AND 
      (acceptedfordeliverytime >= '2012-09-01' AND 
       acceptedfordeliverytime < '2013-01-30'
      )
```

This will also allow an index on `(username, acceptedfordeliverytime)` to be used when executing the query.

Comment: Can you give a little explanation on ` index on (username, acceptedfordeliverytime)`

Comment: That would be an index that would probably help the query run faster.

Comment: Sorry to say.. I don't know how use index :( Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will give you the same results.
and also make an index for column acceptedfordeliverytime to speed up searching.

```
WHERE username = 'xyz' AND acceptedfordeliverytime BETWEEN '2012-9-1' AND '2013-1-29'
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't BETWEEN inclusive? This would mean that you don't need all the extra clauses (that check for the first and last date in a VERY elaborate way). I believe your query would return the same result if you just did:

```
WHERE username = 'xyz' AND 
( 
    acceptedfordeliverytime BETWEEN '2012-9-1' AND '2013-1-29'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your both OR part is unnecessary.

when you use

```
acceptedfordeliverytime  Between '2012-9-1' AND '2013-1-29'
```

It used both date included so OR part is not needed. if you have date and time in your database then you can convert it into date like this

```
CAST(acceptedfordeliverytime as date)  Between '2012-9-1' AND '2013-1-29'
```